# input arabic characters with scanner in maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, java.util.scanner

i work on netbeans 8.2 and i create a java maven project, i want just take an input with arabic characters and display it and that don't work properly :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("enter arabic word = ");
    
    String p = sc.nextLine() ; // input = ياسين
    
    System.out.println("here is your word =  " + p); //output = J'3JF
```

NOTES: i have already change netbeans configuration (/etc/netbeans.conf) to accept UTF-8 encoding but i have this probleme just with MAVEN projects.

Comment: This works for me in for example, IntelliJ IDEA and at the command line in OS X

Comment: maybe i will change my IDE to Intellij also it is more intelligence than netbeans or eclipse, i have always like this problems taking my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run code in other environment. May NetBeans doesn't support UTF-8. 
Old but may still actual article: https://www.google.com/amp/s/ditoinfo.wordpress.com/2007/02/26/netbeans-and-utf8-encoding-2/amp/?espv=1

Comment: the same code if i create a java project it will run wery well but if i create a java maven project it will not display me arabic characters.